# How to use different authentication_keys for two devise models?

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3, models, devise

Now I have one devise model, which uses email as authentication_key.

I want to add one new devise model, which uses student_id as authentication_key.

Some guide tells me to modify the configuration

"config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]" by replacing the :email with :student_id.

After modification, the first model login always fails, so I think I have to indicate different authentication_keys for the two models separately.

How should I do?

Answer (score 89):

You will have to declare inside your models which are the authenitcation keys, rather than inside the devise.rb file.

```
class model1 < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :authentication_keys => [:email]
```

and for your second model

```
class model2 < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :authentication_keys => [:studentid]
```

also make sure that you comment out from devise.rb the config.authentication_keys settings

Comment: Roy, if the answer is suitable then please feel free to mark it as a correct answer (I am trying to build some reputation!). Many thanks!

Comment: This just saved my arse while implementing an app which sits atop Refinery CMS which uses Devise for its own authentication. Thanks!

Comment: yeah dude give him some credit and mark it as correct answer! ;) (worked for me too...)

Comment: Important: If you're using Recoverable, make sure you add ````:reset_password_keys => [:email]````, otherwise the password resets will always be scoped on :email (!)